# Is there a way to plot large datasets with a laptop?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, large-data

my `time series`  which I gain from simulated data is too big(350Mb) to plot it (I want to do it with `dygraph` ) . Is there any way to make my dataset smaller , but don't loose to many information?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I see one of your tags is `time-series`. You could aggregate the data by time intervals. Say if your data is reported with per-second resolution, and you need only hourly results, then aggregating by hour will reduce your data to about 350 Mb/3600 ≅ 100 Kb.